# Applying a subscripting function within a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension, apply

I have a a column with lists of numbers and have written a function to take the even numbers of the list if the first number of the list is even and the odd numbers if the first number of the list is odd. However, I am running into a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` when running my script.

```
def remove(val):
  even = []
  odd = []
  if val[0] % 2 == 0:
    for i in val:
      if (i % 2 == 0):
        even.append(i)
    return even
  else:
    for i in val:
      if (i % 2 != 0):
        odd.append(i)
    return odd

df.B = df.A.apply(remove)
```

The expected result would be something like below:

```
       A               B    
[1,2,3,4,5,6]       [1,3,5]
[2,3,4,5,6,7]       [2,4,6]
      ...             ...
```

I am realizing that there is most likely a more eloquent way to build my function with list comprehension but this seemed the most obvious.

Comment: are you sure there is a list in each cell of the column A? maybe you have missing values? what gives `type(df.loc[0,'A'])`?

Comment: The type is a `list`, i've checked and there are no missing values.

Comment: You need to share input data as it is in your real case. using `X` as defined in the answer of Nirf, then your function works. There is probably a problem with your data quality

Comment: There was an issue with my data quality. Its a data set with thousands of observations though so will have to come up with some more filtering to boil it down into a format I can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `.apply()` correctly. try:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6,7]]})
X['B'] = X.apply(lambda x: remove(x[0]),axis=1)
```

Also, if you'd like a solution which doesn't use an extrernal function:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6,7]]})

X['B'] = X.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x[0] if i % 2 == 0] if x[0][0]%2 == 0 else [i for i in x[0] if i % 2 == 1],axis=1)
```

Comment: Did these solutions work for you? I tried running both and they both resulted in errors. 
Also, my understanding is that both these statements are equivalent:
`df['B'] = df.apply(lamda x: function(x[0]), axis=1)`
`df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lamda x: function(x), axis=1)`

Comment: It does. in this solution I assumed that the column with the lists ('A') is the first column. Make sure it is the same in yours, and if not do the needed changes in the code.

Comment: `lambda x: x[0]`  works on the first column @rweber

Comment: @rweber I don't think you can specify an axis when applying on a column but other then that `X['B'] = X.apply(lambda x: remove(x[0]),axis=1)` and  `X['B'] = X['A'].apply(lambda x: remove(x))` are equivalent.